# mysql generate missing dates with previous value

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is a mysql table which has sparse dates.

```
col dt_id  value
A1 2018-05-28 30
A1 2018-05-30 20
A1 2018-05-31 50
A1 2018-06-01 50
A1 2018-06-04 80
A1 2018-06-05 50
```

The output should be something like below where missing dates are populated along with the last value.

```
col dt_id  value
A1 2018-05-28 30
A1 2018-05-29 30
A1 2018-05-30 20
A1 2018-05-31 50
A1 2018-06-01 50
A1 2018-06-02 50
A1 2018-06-03 50
A1 2018-06-04 80
A1 2018-06-05 50
```

here the following were generated.

```
A1 2018-05-29 30
A1 2018-06-02 50
A1 2018-06-03 50
```

I know solutions with oracle using `last_value() over (partition by..`, but since this is mysql, its a bit tricky.

Here is what i've tried:

create a time table and populate with data:

```
CREATE TABLE `time_table` (date_id date not null);
create table ints ( i tinyint ); insert into ints values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9); 

insert into time_table (date_id) select date('2016-09-01')+ interval a.i*10000 + b.i*1000 + c.i*100 + d.i*10 + e.i day 
from ints a 
join ints b 
join ints c 
join ints d 
join ints e 
where (a.i*10000 + b.i*1000 + c.i*100 + d.i*10 + e.i) <= 11322 order by 1;

select * from time_table limit 10;
+------------+
| date_id    |
+------------+
| 2018-09-22 |
| 2018-09-21 |
| 2018-09-20 |
| 2018-09-19 |
| 2018-09-18 |
| 2018-09-17 |
| 2018-09-16 |
| 2018-09-15 |
| 2018-09-14 |
| 2018-09-13 |
+------------+

Here is the data for the balance table:
Here is the data
+------+------------+-------+
| A1   | 2018-05-28 |    30 |
| A1   | 2018-05-30 |    20 |
| A1   | 2018-05-31 |    50 |
| A1   | 2018-06-01 |    50 |
| A1   | 2018-06-04 |    80 |
| A1   | 2018-06-05 |    50 |
| B1   | 2018-05-28 |    30 |
| B1   | 2018-05-30 |    20 |
| B1   | 2018-05-31 |    50 |
| B1   | 2018-06-01 |    50 |
| B1   | 2018-06-04 |    80 |
| B1   | 2018-06-05 |    50 |
| C1   | 2018-05-28 |    30 |
| C1   | 2018-05-30 |    20 |
| C1   | 2018-05-31 |    50 |
| C1   | 2018-06-01 |    50 |
| C1   | 2018-06-04 |    80 |
| C1   | 2018-06-05 |    50 |
| D1   | 2018-06-28 |    30 |
| D1   | 2018-07-02 |    20 |
| D1   | 2018-07-04 |    50 |
| D1   | 2018-07-08 |    80 |
| D1   | 2018-07-19 |    50 |
+------+------------+-------+


mysql> select b.id, ab.id, tt.`date_id` as cal_date, b.`mx` as ex_date, val
    -> from time_table tt
    -> inner join (select id, min(date_id) mi, max(date_id) mx from balance group by id) b
    -> on tt.`date_id` >= b.`mi`
    -> and tt.`date_id` <= b.mx
    -> left join (select id, date_id, sum(value) val from balance group by id, date_id) ab
    -> on ab.id = b.id and tt.`date_id` = ab.date_id
    -> order by cal_date;
+------+------+------------+------------+------+
| id   | id   | cal_date   | ex_date    | val  |
+------+------+------------+------------+------+
| A1   | A1   | 2018-05-28 | 2018-06-05 |   30 |
| A1   | NULL | 2018-05-29 | 2018-06-05 | NULL |
| A1   | A1   | 2018-05-30 | 2018-06-05 |   20 |
| A1   | A1   | 2018-05-31 | 2018-06-05 |   50 |
| A1   | A1   | 2018-06-01 | 2018-06-05 |   50 |
| A1   | NULL | 2018-06-02 | 2018-06-05 | NULL |
| A1   | NULL | 2018-06-03 | 2018-06-05 | NULL |
| A1   | A1   | 2018-06-04 | 2018-06-05 |   80 |
| A1   | A1   | 2018-06-05 | 2018-06-05 |   50 |
+------+------+------------+------------+------+
```

Comment: Can you share your current code? What exactly is giving you the results you're getting?

Comment: Updated the original post on what I've tried. I'm not able to fixx the NULL value with the previous value and thats where I'm seeking help.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MySQL 8:

```
with recursive rcte(dt_id, col, value) as (
  (
    select dt_id, col, value
    from mytable
    order by dt_id
    limit 1
  )
  union all
  select r.dt_id + interval 1 day
       , coalesce(t.col, r.col)     
       , coalesce(t.value, r.value)
  from rcte r
  left join mytable t on t.dt_id = r.dt_id + interval 1 day
  where r.dt_id < (select max(dt_id) from mytable)
)
select r.col, r.dt_id, r.value
from rcte r
order by r.dt_id
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sYjyWPoc44MstYvPYcD1Bs/0)

The recursive query will build row by row incrementing the date starting from the first date until the last. The `value` (and `col`) is taken from the original table, which is left joined on date. If the original table doesn't have a row for a date, the value of the last row in the recursion is taken instead.

For older versions you can use your calendar table and a subquery in the left joins ON clause to get last existing values:

```
select b.col, c.date_id, b.value
from time_table c
left join balance b on b.dt_id = (
  select max(dt_id)
  from balance b1
  where b1.dt_id <= c.date_id
)
where c.date_id >= (select min(dt_id) from balance)
  and c.date_id <= (select max(dt_id) from balance)
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4fJSJzJrFySt4eLw5TUsaT/0)

#### Update

Since the question has changed:

```
select b.col, c.date_id, b.value
from (
  select col, min(dt_id) as min_dt, max(dt_id) as max_dt
  from balance
  group by col
) i
join time_table c
  on  c.date_id >= i.min_dt
  and c.date_id <= i.max_dt
left join balance b
  on  b.col = i.col
  and b.dt_id = (
    select max(dt_id)
    from balance b1
    where b1.dt_id <= c.date_id
      and b1.col = i.col
)
order by b.col, c.date_id
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9CBq6BFRRXi8AyntxpDzQv/0)

Make sure you have an index on `(col, dt_id)`. In best case it would be the primary key. `date_id` in the `time_table` should also be indexed or the primary key.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! this works provided when balance table has only 1 ID - in this case `A1`. What if there are other rows such as `B1` and `C1`? This is also some 200k rows. So should be performant.

Comment: It should also work for different "IDs" ([db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/88h64Dyr4m7qtRpzuSS7rB/0)). It depends on what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say, B1 key having its own dates and C1 key having its own dates. I've updated the data in the balance table accordingly.

Comment: See the update. It's probably not the fastest solution - it depends on how the engine can optimize the joins. If you need a high performance solution, you should probably write a stored procedure, filling the gaps in loops.

Comment: thank you! this works like a charm. I was close in getting the same, but the dt_id <= date_id messed it up for me.