# Mysql, get data between two dates, if there is not data at the starting date, I need to get data from last entered date?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with following entries

| Created at | tax |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-05 | 300 |
| 2020-06-10 | 350 |
| 2020-09-15 | 400 |
| 2020-09-28 | 320 |

If I try to get data between 2020-02-01 to 2020-10-30 I need to get output as following

| Created at | tax |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-02-01 | 300 |
| 2020-03-01 | 300 |
| 2020-04-01 | 300 |
| 2020-05-01 | 300 |
| 2020-06-01 | 300 |
| 2020-06-10 | 350 |
| 2020-07-01 | 350 |
| 2020-08-01 | 350 |
| 2020-09-01 | 350 |
| 2020-09-15 | 400 |
| 2020-09-28 | 320 |
| 2020-10-01 | 320 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql generate missing dates with previous value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56383199/mysql-generate-missing-dates-with-previous-value)

Comment: And this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range

Comment: It does but partially. If from date doesn't have data, then I need to get data from last entered date (if exists) and output it as a from date and so on.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: There is no coding attempt included in this "requirements dump".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MySQl 8` you can generate the missing records recursively. Otherwise, a temporary table is required.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE dates (created_at) AS (
  SELECT '2020-02-01' as created_at
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  FROM dates WHERE created_at <= '2020-10-30'
), result_table AS (
  SELECT created_at, tax FROM taxes
  UNION 
  SELECT created_at, (
      SELECT tax FROM taxes t 
      WHERE t.created_at <= d.created_at 
      ORDER BY t.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
    ) AS tax
  FROM dates d
)   
SELECT * FROM result_table
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-10-30'
ORDER BY 1
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0eeca2a9a0b80ef895daab2ce54534c2)

Comment: Can you suggest me way of doing same query using temporary table.

Comment: Look at this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d61e18d27c8300b3a9ff4c33b5ebe512). There are many other ways to create a temporary table specifically for this task. For example, by creating a table and inserting records, creating a stored procedure, or even building an entire SQL statement with fiddle's temp part named `months` using PHP (as you tagged the question with `php` tag). All of this applies if the MySQL version is lower than 8.