# How to generate a row per day?

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume a table like this:

```
# wallet 
+----+----------+------------------+------------+
| id | user_id  |     balance      |    date    |
+----+----------+------------------+------------+
| 1  | 5        | 1000             | 2022-10-01 |
| 2  | 5        | 800              | 2022-10-03 |
| 3  | 5        | 700              | 2022-10-03 |
| 4  | 5        | 1200             | 2022-10-06 |
+----+----------+------------------+------------+
```

I want to get the minimum balance per day (if there is more than one row) and repeat it for each day until the next existing row. Something like this:

```
+----------+------------------+------------+
| user_id  |     balance      |    date    |
+----------+------------------+------------+
| 5        | 1000             | 2022-10-01 |
| 5        | 1000             | 2022-10-02 |
| 5        | 700              | 2022-10-03 |
| 5        | 700              | 2022-10-04 |
| 5        | 700              | 2022-10-05 |
| 5        | 1200             | 2022-10-06 |
+----------+------------------+------------+
```

See? from `2022-10-01` until `2022-10-06` we have a row per day. Any idea how can I do that?

---

Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT user_id, MIN(balance), date
FROM wallet
GROUP BY user_id, date
```

But it returns something like this:

```
+----------+------------------+------------+
| user_id  |     balance      |    date    |
+----------+------------------+------------+
| 5        | 1000             | 2022-10-01 |
| 5        | 700              | 2022-10-03 |
| 5        | 1200             | 2022-10-06 |
+----------+------------------+------------+
```

All I need to add is just "repeating a row for the next not existing days". How can I do that?

Comment: you need to outer-join with a *calendar table*

Comment: @Stu Yeah right .. isn't there any approach to simulate a calendar table by a query?

Comment: Of course there is - many are built dynamically, just use a CTE that returns rows generated by row_number() that you can join with. Assuming MySql 8 of course.

Answer (score 1):

**[Answer taken from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56383199/mysql-generate-missing-dates-with-previous-value)**

You can use:

```
with recursive rcte(date, user_id, balance) as (
  (
    select date, user_id, balance
    from wallet
    order by date
    limit 1
  )
  union all
  select r.date + interval 1 day
       , coalesce(t.user_id, r.user_id)     
       , coalesce(t.balance, r.balance)
  from rcte r
  left join wallet t on t.date = r.date + interval 1 day
  where r.date < (select max(date) from wallet)
)
select r.user_id, min(r.balance) as balance,r.date
from rcte r
group by r.user_id,r.date
order by r.date
```

The recursive query will build row by row incrementing the date starting from the first date until the last.

If the table has only one balance per date you could use:

```
with recursive rcte(date, user_id, balance) as (
  (
    select date, user_id, balance
    from wallet
    order by date
    limit 1
  )
  union all
  select r.date + interval 1 day
       , coalesce(t.user_id, r.user_id)     
       , coalesce(t.balance, r.balance)
  from rcte r
  left join wallet t on t.date = r.date + interval 1 day
  where r.date < (select max(date) from wallet)
)
select r.user_id, r.balance,r.date
from rcte r
order by r.date
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/IjqsEC8o